# PHP returns the word array

Tags: php, arrays, return

I have this php code:

```
$tunnid = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $tunnid[] = $row['total'];

  }

$this->set('tunnid', $tunnid);
mysql_free_result($result);
```

And to display it, i have this:

```
<?php
if(!empty($tunnid)) {
    foreach($tunnid as $tund) {
echo "$tunnid";

    }

}
```

For some reason this returns ArrayArrayArrayArray

What am i doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: You are casting arrays to strings.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/17094288/476

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a little typo

```
<?php
if(!empty($tunnid)) {
     foreach($tunnid as $tund) {
     echo "$tund"; //not tunnid

   }

}
```

Comment: Indeed, stupid of me :) I will mark this as the right answer after 12 minutes, however, now it returns 144904782467667666689479742521 etc. How do i get them to separate?

Comment: need to format the string you can use `printf("%s\n", $tund)`